# Why is peer discovery failing on my private ethereum network?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I am trying to set up a private ethereum network to run within a set of 5 machines connected over LAN. As mentioned in the ethereum documentation I used a custom `--networkid 15693` to set up the network, however when I run `geth` on different machines and form some initial connections using `admin.addPeer()` it just stays that way; the peer discovery doesn't seem to be working. For example, I have nodes `1`, `2`, and `3` such that connections are `1--2` and `2--3`, so why is `3` not able to discover `1` ?

**EDIT**
If I setup the network locally(within a machine) then nodes are able to discover and connect to each other, however over the LAN it fails.